# display different number of tabPanels in a navbarPage in Shiny, without renderUI or uiOutput

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to display from 1 to 5 `tabPanels` in a `navbarPage` in Shiny.

I have 5 plots my code generates, but I'd like a user to be able to select how many they want to have access to -- to be displayed one plot in each `tabPanel`, naturally.

I've got an external configuration file (`config.txt`) that via `source('config.txt')`, I have access to a `number_of_pages` variable.

For example, `number_of_tabPages <- 3`

How would I set this up in `UI.R`?

The number of tabPanels can't be hardcoded at all in the UI file, since it depends on a value that is specified by a user, not using a control.

I've searched around and found that most of the approaches to this kind of thing 
involve using `uiOutput` and `renderUI` functions, such as this [similar](http://tiku.io/questions/221938/r-shiny-add-tabpanel-to-tabsetpanel-dynamicaly-with-the-use-of-renderui) problem, but I don't want any special control in the UI to do any selecting.

This is where things get tricky, when we are building the UI depending on values that may change. My brain is trying to wrap itself around the best method for doing this type of thing -- I feel like it isn't exactly in line with how Shiny wants to communicate with itself using a UI <--> server environment.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

My UI.R is easy to create when it isn't dynamic:

```
fluidRow(
column(12,
       "", 
       navbarPage("",tabPanel("First Tab", 
                              plotOutput("plot1")),

                  tabPanel("Second Tab",
                           plotOutput("plot2")),

                  tabPanel("Third Tab",
                           plotOutput("plot3")),

                  tabPanel("Fourth Tab",
                           plotOutput("plot4")),

                  tabPanel("Fifth Tab",
                           plotOutput("plot5"))
                  )
       )
)
)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't need the user to change the number of `tabPanel` interactively, but just load varying numbers of them when the app is started you can use the `do.call` function in the `navBarPage`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(shiny)
library(ggvis)

#number of tabs needed
number_of_tabPages <- 10

#make a list of all the arguments you want to pass to the navbarPage function
tabs<-list()
#first element will be the title, empty in your example
tabs[[1]]=""

#add all the tabPanels to the list
for (i in 2:(number_of_tabPages+1)){
  tabs[[i]]=tabPanel(paste0("Tab",i-1),plotOutput(paste0("plot",i-1)))

}

 #do.call will call the navbarPage function with the arguments in the tabs list
shinyUI(fluidRow(
  column(12,
         "", 
         do.call(navbarPage,tabs)
         )
  )
)
```